# Inserting Block of XML into SQL XML Field

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a field in my tabled called `Details` which contains an `xml` string of optional  fields a user may fill out and looks like this:

```
<optional>
 <name>Value</name>
 <account>123</account>
</optional>
```

I am trying to insert a block of `xml` into that field within a query that looks like so:

```
SELECT  SUBMITTEDON AS 'SubmitDate',
        'coachingOpp' AS 'Type',
        R.ReasonID AS 'reasonID',
        'TLReview' AS 'status',
        'Pending' AS outcome,
        '<optional>' +
        '<name>' + P.TICKET + '</name>' +
        '<account>' + P.CUSTOMERACCOUNTNUMBER + '</account>' +
        '</optional>' AS 'Details',
        ISNULL(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(P.REQUESTDETAILS + ' --- ' + P.[MESSAGE], '&', '&amp;'), '<', '&lt;'), '>', '&gt;'), '"', '&quot;'), '''', '&#39;'),'No PET Data Available')
```

If I remove the `INSERT` part of the code and just leave the select, it displays all of the records fine. However, when I am trying to insert the record from the select statement, I get the following error:

```
Msg 9421, Level 16, State 1, Procedure InsertFeedback, Line 42
XML parsing: line 1, character 118, illegal name character
```

The selecting of the data seems to run fine; just errors out when trying to insert that data into the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the contents of P.TICKET and P.CUSTOMERACCOUNTNUMBER.
However I would let SQL generate the XML for you instead of doing it manually.

```
SELECT Ticket name, CUSTOMERACCOUNTNUMBER ticket FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('Optional')
```

That can be a subquery or use cross apply.

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest answer of your question. You must convert string into xml like.

```
declare @xmlstring varchar(200) = '<optional>
 <name>Value</name>
 <account>123</account>
</optional>'

declare @convertStringtoXml xml = cast ( @xmlstring as xml)

create table #t  (xmlfld xml)
insert into #t values(@convertStringtoXml)  

select * from #t

drop table #t
```